# API request constantly returning Invalid HTTP status code 405, but command line works

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a pretty basic authentication system. However, I am requesting the login data from a different app. My angular app is running on `3030` and my app with authentication runs on `3000`.

To test that it works ahead of time, I request it from the command line.

```
$ http post http://localhost:3000/api/v1/login user="email@email.org" password="password"

{
  "data": {
    "authToken": "xxxx",
    "userId": "userid"
  },
  "status": "success"
}
```

In my app running on port `3030`, I have a very simple authentication system.

```
angular.module('Auth')
  .controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {
      // same as the data from the above request
      $scope.credentials = {
        user: '',
        password: ''
      };

      $scope.authenticate = function () {
        $http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/login', $scope.credentials)
          .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
          })
          .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
          })
      }
    }
  ]);
```

(here is the simplified view in case it helps to answer)

```
<form name="login" ng-submit="authenticate()">
  <input name="user" type="email" ng-model="credentials.user" />
  <input name="password" type="password" ng-model="credentials.password" />
</form>
```

However, this keeps giving me errors in the console.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/v1/login. Invalid HTTP status code 405

Why is it that this works on the command line, but it does not work within the application?

Comment: If you are on windows, you can use Fiddler to watch the http requests ... http://www.telerik.com/fiddler ... then you can see if there really is a difference.

Comment: HTTP 405 means "Method not Allowed". Are you sure your API allows the usage of the HTTP method you are using (POST in this case)? If you are on Windows use Fiddler to find out what is actually going on with your request/response.

Comment: That was my thought too, but I did test posting to it from the command line and it worked plenty fine

Comment: ah. On looking into the resource inspector, it seems like the request type was `OPTIONS`... guess it's a CORS thing